# docker pull from default registry "registry-1.docker.io" failing with x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker

I have docker-ce:17.06.2-ce installed in my machine (Ubuntu:14.04). When I pull any image from docker repository, I'm seeing authentication error:

```
$ docker pull hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/hello-world/manifests/latest: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fhello-world%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
See 'docker run --help'
```

Why I am seeing this error ? And is it required to have any certificates in system ? If yes, what certificates to be installed to avoid this ?

Comment: Do you use a proxy? Are you on a VPN/Corporate network? If you curl the url directly, do you have the same certificate error? I already have this issue on a corporate network that intercept the http query and without the ssl certificate from the vendor, the certificate was rejected by my applications

Comment: try this not sure will help log in through command line/terminal by typing docker login will username & password put username / pass then try to pull the image

Comment: Hi @jmaitrehenry
Yes, I am on corporate VPN. So did you mean that either corporate network should trust the docker registry or provide certs to install in my machine ?? How did you solve this in your case ?